# Set width of space with iText 7

Tags: java, itext7

Is there a way to set the width of all spaces in a Paragraph in iText 7?

So for example when showing the text "Hello world spacetest" I would like to be able to set the space between "Hello" and "world", and the space between "world" and "spacetest" to 3em.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Paragraph#setWordSpacing` for that: e.g. `p.setWordSpacing(10);`.
Full code sample:

```
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outFileName));

Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);

Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Hello world spacetest");
p.setWordSpacing(10);
document.add(p);

document.close();
```

Visual result:

[image: result]

Comment: Hi, what's the minimum value for word spacing? It's not work when set word spacing as 2f.